# has_many/belongs_to relationships & query questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, sqlite

I am building an attendance tracker right now. I have three models currently. I am using devise for my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  has_many :attendances

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :attendances

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client
```

The columns on the attendance table are `user_id` `client_id` `created_at` and `updated_at`

Here's my thought process:
I can get all of the attendances for each `User`
I can also get all of the attendances for a specific `Client`
I can get all of the attendance records for a specific `User` and `Client` by way of: `Attendance.joins(:user, :client).where(:user_id => current_user)` which returns an

`<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Attendance id: 18, client_id: 151, created_at: "2015-07-24 21:36:16", updated_at: "2015-07-24 21:36:16", user_id: 4>, #<Attendance id: 19, client_id: 101, created_at: "2015-07-24 21:37:10", updated_at: "2015-07-24 21:37:10", user_id: 4>, #<Attendance id: 20, client_id: 114, created_at: "2015-07-24 21:37:39", updated_at: "2015-07-24 21:37:39", user_id: 4>, #<Attendance id: 21, client_id: 123, created_at: "2015-07-24 21:38:26", updated_at: "2015-07-24 21:38:26", user_id: 4>]>`

Can I somehow refer back to `Client` table to get information like `first_name` or `email` with another `where`, `include`, or `joins` statement?

Or am I missing something altogether and maybe need a join table and do a `has_many, through:` relationship?

Comment: You have access to all of that already. `attendences.each {|a| p a.client.first_name }` or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: `Attendance.joins(:user, :client).where(:user_id => current_user).select('clients.*')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brad's comment above is technically correct, but since the `.joins` clause on your query only includes those tables for the execution of the actual query, the data from the Users and Clients tables isn't actually going to get loaded in by Rails, so in order to fetch all their data you'll end up executing N+1 queries (a common cause of slow Rails apps!). That is:

```
irb> User.joins(:groups).each { |u| u.groups.map(&:name) }
  User Load (8.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."user_id" = "users"."id"
  Group Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Group Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Group Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Group Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 2]]
  Group Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 3]]
```

Not so bad now, but imagine if you had a thousand users! We can fix this, though. If you use the `.includes` method, you'll both join onto the other table(s) and load their data into memory. It still runs 2 queries, but that's an improvement:

```
irb(main):016:0> User.includes(:groups).each { |u| u.groups.map(&:name) }
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  Group Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."user_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

So, for your case, try this instead:

```
Attendance.includes(:user, :client).where(user_id: current_user)
```

For more info on the difference between `includes` and `joins`, see [this blog post](http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/), or Google "rails joins vs includes".

Comment: Thanks Robert. That solved that issue for me, but then it brought up another one. I can get all of those records that I need for a specific user or client and attendances. Is there an efficient way to string those includes/joins to then use the foreign `client_id` to get say the first_name or address of said specific client?

Comment: Assuming those are just attributes on the `Client` record, this will be fairly efficient (involving only the same 2 queries as I mentioned above): `@client_first_names = Attendance.includes(:user, :client).where(user_id: current_user).map { |attendance| attendance.client.first_name }`. You can break that out onto multiple lines to make it easier to read!

Comment: Also, if you for some reason *only* want the names, you could do: `Attendance.joins(:user, :client).where(user_id: current_user).pluck('clients.first_name')`. See [here](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/05/29/how-to-pluck-like-a-rails-pro/) for more info on what I'm doing there.

Comment: Wow. That absolutely works in both cases, thanks for that. I didn't think about using `.map` with the `.includes` method. This has been driving me insane!